# Calculus - Help with this series $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{9k^2+3k-2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{9k^2+3k-2}$$

**My solution**

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{9k^2+3k-2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3k(3k+1)-2}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{40}+\frac{1}{88}+...+\frac{1}{3k(3k+1)-2}$$

I understand that it converge (since r<1), but I need to find the sum.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the fact that $9k^2 +3k - 2 = (3k + 2)(3k - 1)$ to write $S_n$ as a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: $$\frac1{9k^2+3k-2}=\frac1{(3k-1)(3k+2)}=\frac13\left(\frac1{3k-1}-\frac1{3k+2}\right)$$

Comment: M.Scott I thought about it the problem is that $$
\frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k+2}=\frac{3k+2-(3k-1)}{(3k-1)(3k+2)}=\frac{3k+2-3k+1}{(3k-1)(3k+2)}=\frac{3}{(3k-1)(3k+2)} \neq \frac{1}{(3k-1)(3k+2)}$$

Comment: @JaVaPG: That’s why I have that factor of $\frac13$ in the final expression. Your series is $$\frac13\sum_{k\ge 1}\left(\frac1{3k-1}-\frac1{3k+2}\right)\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in hints the following holds:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{9k^2 + 3k-2} &= \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k+2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left[ \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3n+2} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3k+2} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{6}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $9k^2+3k-2=(3k-1)(3k+2)$.